# new page redirect to old page which had the same permalink

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I had a page on /features/
and a newer page on /features-2/

I wanted the newer page to get the more pretty slug /features/
So i did the following:

/features/ => /features-old/
/features-2/ => /features/
But when I go into /features/ now I'm sent to /features-old/

Answer (score 1):

Did you add that in your htaccess file

You're basically saying if you land on /features take me to /features-old which is what is meant to happen by your code.

It's easy to fix though, go to the WP pages and change their slugs, you don't need to mess with redirects.